# Not "x" or "y" without using -v in grep/pgrep filter?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to write a bash command using the pgrep expression that uses the -U option and omits certain processes. Because of this I cannot use -v to inverse my search.

I can easily get two processes saying:

```
pgrep -U $UID 'x|y'
```

However I am looking to omit the two processes x and y as well as get only my processes.

Is there a regular expression way of saying grep not-x and not-y?

Comment: `^(?:(?!x|y).)+$`

Comment: Or by the numbers, exclude 821 and 659 `^([^86][0-9]*|8([^2][0-9]*|2([^1][0-9]*)?)?|6([^5][0-9]*|5([^9][0-9]*)?)?)$` Names are done the same way. They're all just characters.

Comment: Not possible with pgrep.

Comment: As per documentation `-v
    Negates the matching. `  https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Answer (score -1):

So the goal is pgrep pattern1 but not pattern2 neither something so solution sould be
with an example :

pattern1 is 24

pattern2 is not 8 neither 9

```
pgrep bash | grep '24[^8-9][0-9]'
```

adding or not `-l` to pgrep command if needed.

Comment: The goal is to find all pids that A. belong to a given user, B. are *not* the program names "x" or "y".

Answer (score -1):

List process's PID and process name for specific user. Ignore the pattern you don't need and then just print the PID.

```
pgrep -U $UID -l | egrep -v "x|y" | cut -d " " -f1
```

Comment: as said in comments egrep and cut may be returned also, however using a variable could be   the solution `tmp=$(pgrep ..); <<<"$tmp" egrep ...`

Comment: even using variable bash subshell is returned